# How to scrape the data of this specific website?

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape the on duty drugstores out of a website "https://www.pharmacie.be/?max_results=50&txt-zip=1000"

[image]

but the content doesnt show when using beautifulSoup or Selenium; so I guess it is Javascript generated. is there a way to reach the content ?

This is the selenium version code.

```
url = "https://www.pharmacie.be/?max_results=50&txt-zip=1000"
from selenium import webdriver
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
options.add_argument('--incognito')# access the browser in incognito mode
options.add_argument('--headless') # access the browser without having to open it

driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:/webdrivers/chromedriver79.exe", options=options)
driver.get(url)
page = driver.page_source
```

Any idea on how to acces the `<div class="api-results">` tag ?

Thx

Comment: `driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='api-results']")` if the first element with calss of api-results is the one you are looking for.

Comment: If you're using selenium, then it shouldn't matter if the site is loaded asynchronously. The failures I've seen with selenium in cases like this are down to any of: not waiting for the page to finish loading before searching, not searching for the correct path/element, or being blocked by the site because they've detected you as a bot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data is loaded via Javascript, so you can use `selenium` to obtain it, or you can use `requests` and execute queries manually:

For example:

```
import json
import requests

search_term = '1000 bruxelles'

url1 = 'https://api.tomtom.com/search/2/geocode/{}.json?key=ixTHgmn1oIBAMGhFbkAWgG5ajGKI4psb&limit=1&countrySet=BE'
url2 = 'https://api.geowacht.be/api-v4/json/pharmacies/near_coordinate?&latitude={}&longitude={}&jsonp=?&max_distance=30&max_results=5&language=fr'

data = requests.get(url1.format(search_term)).json()

lat, lon = data['results'][0]['position']['lat'], data['results'][0]['position']['lon']

data = requests.get(url2.format(lat, lon), headers={'Api-user-agent':'gwapi.js/4.0 (pharmacie.be)'}).json()

# print(json.dumps(data, indent=4)) # <-- uncomment to see all data

for result in data['results']:
    print(result['pharmacy']['name'])
    print(result['pharmacy']['address_street'], result['pharmacy']['address_streetnr'])
    print(result['pharmacy']['address_postalcode'], result['pharmacy']['address_locality'])
    print('-' * 80)
```

Prints:

```
Pharmacie Tsiokanos
Rue des Fripiers 24
1000 Bruxelles
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Pharmacie Etoile du Nord-Jumatex
Rue du Progrès 27
1210 Saint-Josse-ten-Noode
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Pharmacie Du Midi
Avenue Fonsny 29
1060 Saint-Gilles
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Pharmacie de la Duch.de Brabant
Place de la Duchesse de Brabant 39
1080 Molenbeek-Saint-Jean
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Pharmacie Elouriaghli Salwa
Chaussée de Merchtem 98
1080 Molenbeek-Saint-Jean
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```